При применении миграции не появляется папка migrations
развернул django проект на сервере однако после применения
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
не появляется папка migrations с миграциями из-за чего django проект не работает должным образом
И да при python manage.py showmigrations вижу это:
admin
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
[X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
[X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
[X] 0004_alter_user_username_optsaaa
[X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
[X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
[X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
[X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
[X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
[X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
[X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
[X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
contenttypes
[X] 0001_initial
[X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
[X] 0001_initial

Мигрировать БД стоит ещё до развёртывания Django-приложения, а после весь проект вместе с мигрированной базой данной развернуть на сервере.
